# PHP check for global variable before loading pages

Tags: php, variables, directory, global-variables, ini

I want all PHP pages in a directory to only load if a PHP variable is present and valid. I know how to do this on a single or even multiple pages manually, but I want this to happen to all pages in a directory automatically. Is there some type of setting I can put in a php.ini file that will allow me to do this.

Comment: This is one advantage to a framework. In a framework, you never really load other files without loading your *base set of files*. I'd recommend, if you're not using one, to at least mimic them in this regard. Make your php files all include one file. In that file, make sure all the logic happens that must take place before anything else. This is also great because you can make sure your headers never get sent in more than one place.

Comment: There's no way to do this just for one directory. There's a global `auto_prepend_file` option, but it applies to all scripts in all directories.

Comment: The directory I want to limit access to is filled with files from a 3rd party. I have no control over if they use a framework or not. I agree 100% with your comment though, if only it was that easy for me. I need to avoid touching the code as much as possible.

Comment: @Barmar What if the directory is represented by a sub domain? I have a main domain that I want to leave alone, but everything on my sub domain is in fact the directory its self.

Comment: I think that should work, because each domain can have its own `php.ini`.

Comment: Can't you just use a simple shell script to edit all the files in the directory and insert the check?

Comment: @Barmar I could, but like I said I want to avoid touching the 3rd party code as much as I can. If the sub domain doesn't work I may have to do that though.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an if statement to each page checking to see if the session variable is set. Why edit the ini file?

Comment: I want to block access to the directory as a whole. There are thousands of files, adding an if statement to check for a variable on each one wouldn't be practical.

Comment: @MitchMitchell if none of those files are supposed to be accessed directly (browser, another script - ajax, etc), then you can consider adding a .htaccess (or similar method if you aren't using apache)?

Comment: @OliverMaksimovic They should be accessed, but only when a global variable has the correct value. I don't want to cut access completely

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using htaccess. Create an htaccess file in the directory you want to protect with the code below in it.

**.htaccess file**

php_value auto_prepend_file "/path/globalchecker.php"

**globalchecker.php**

```
<?php 
 if($some_global_value !== 'some value')
    exit;

?>
```